# How to overcome Odom drift while using amcl?

Tags: ros, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros community

How to fix the Odom drift I have only used laser_scan for localisation.

And also When I was doing amcl while launching it, the pose direction is perpendicular to my robot, I played with the params and still it's perpendicular to it.i am using an four wheel drive configuration.

The TF tree is map--->odom---->origin_link--->base_link--->rplidar_link and rest to wheels

When i launch the gazebo with amcl node with parameters. In the rviz the pose array of arrows shows perpendicular to the bot on stationary and when moving its shows in the perpendicular direction and the odom drifts away from map frame i have set the 2D pose estimate but the entire robot model rotates. After gmapping what should I do for robot localisation.

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

Thanks in advance for answering my question

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405385/how-to-overcome-odom-drift-while-using-amcl?/) by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2022-08-23**:
Please rephrase your question and add some pictures and we might be able to help you out better.

**Comment by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) on 2022-08-23**:
Thanks luc for seeing my question i have attached the drive link for the images kindly look into it thank you

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-08-24**:
@YASVANTH-S  for safety reasons, you better upload the picture directly since ros answers supports this feature.

**Comment by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) on 2022-08-25**:
I can understand it CroCo but I am new to ros answers so I don't have enough karma points to upload a picture. Is there any other way to show the image.

**Comment by [iimata](https://answers.ros.org/users/101281/iimata/) on 2022-08-26**:
@YASVANTH-S  try [google drive](https://drive.google.com/)

**Comment by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) on 2022-08-26**:
I increased my karma and included the image kindly look into it

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-08-27**:\

1. What is `origin_link`? This is a non-standard name.
2. Which transforms are static, and which transforms can take new values as the robot moves?
3. In your image, which direction is the +x axis for the `base_link` frame?

**Comment by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) on 2022-08-27**:
Mike Scheutzow for the questions you have asked i have included the images kindly look into it and thank you

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-08-27**:
Your new images do not fully answer my questions. The new info I learned is that `origin_link->base_link` is a static transform, and `odom->origin_link` is published by a node named odom_pub.

**Comment by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) on 2022-08-27**:
Yes from `map -> odom_link` is published by amcl and the x+-axis direction to the bot is 90 degree to the lidar. In the gazebo image the red wheel which is on the red line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was my mistake because the robot is based on `Y axis` but the robot should be based on `X axis`. After I changed my robot axis to `X axis` amcl worked perfectly. If anyone gets this type of problem first check whether your bot is `X axis` based or not and Thank for the community for answering my questions through the comments

---

Originally posted by [YASVANTH-S](https://answers.ros.org/users/115049/yasvanth-s/) with karma: 11 on 2022-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0